# Why does my OS X still run older php even though I updated it?

Tags: macos, mac, php

I have just updated my system php in terminal via command line.

I deleted the export path in .bash_profile as it was pointing to mamp but for some reason my php still says 5.3 not 5.4 when I run `php -v` in terminal.

Does anyone know why this would happen. I have also closed terminal and reopened to see the change.

Comment: How did you update php?

Comment: using this command curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.4

Comment: Can you source your .bash_profile manually? In order to do so do the following: `source ~/.bash_profile`. Run `php -v` after that(without closing your terminal). If it still doesn't work please provide your .bash_profile, .profile and a `echo $PATH` please.

Comment: yes I can source that and this is what I have:

Comment: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as you did not add the new path to your `$PATH`.

Citing the FAQ of the [website](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) that you have posted:

> Why does php -v on the command line still show my old version?
>
> php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but installs everyting in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is therefore in /usr/local/php5/bin/php.
>
> You can also adjust your PATH do include that directory, eg. write into your ~/.profile file the following
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH

So open you .profile or .bash_profile in a editor like nano or vim and add the last line `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` to the appropiate file.

Source your file with `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.profile` or close and reopen your terminal.

Comment: The only issue now when I run homebrew `brew doctor` is I get this error:

Comment: `Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /usr/local/php5/bin/curl-config
    /usr/local/php5/bin/freetype-config
    /usr/local/php5/bin/icu-config
    /usr/local/php5/bin/libmcrypt-config
    /usr/local/php5/bin/libpng-config
    /usr/local/php5/bin/libpng12-config
    /usr/local/php5/bin/php-config
    /usr/local/php5/bin/xml2-config
    /usr/local/php5/bin/xslt-config`

Comment: Since I can't find any other php package at http://braumeister.org/ I think you can safely ignore this as long you don't add any other taps related to php itself. I may be wrong on this and getting corrected(hopefully) if so.

Comment: The key for me was exiting and restarting terminal (had already updated .bash_profile and .profile).

Comment: I had no `.bash_profile` and `.profile` files in my home dir. So I created them by entering `touch .profile` as [stated here](http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/creating-bashprofile-your-mac). I put the `PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` in both the files and now `php -v` shows that the newer PHP version (which is 7.0.10).